# What version of .net has a release key of 395222 and how do I figure this out on my own?

Tags: windows-10, .net-framework

In Visual Studio 15 Preview 5, the About dialog says I have “Microsoft .NET Framework Version 4.6.02006” installed. I am running Windows 10 Insider Preview build `14959.rs_prerelease.161026-1700`. I can’t seem to find any information online.

At [.NET Framework Versions and Dependencies](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb822049%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), the release keys for .net-4.6.2 are said to be 394802 for Windows 10 and 394806 for old supported versions of Windows. Based on the information on that page, the .net framework installed on my computer is newer than .net-4.6.2. But I can’t tell if that just means I have a patched version of .net-4.6.2 or if I have what they’d consider .net-4.6.3-preview or .net-4.7-preview.

I also looked at `%WINDIR%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\clr.dll`’s FileVersion and got `4.6.2006.0`.

Am I supposed to take the `02` and `006` from the `4.6.02006` in Visual Studio to infer that I’m running .net-4.6.2 with a patchlevel of 6 or something?

Comment: @Ramhound I was under the impression that core is quite far from binary compatibility with the framework, but that’s beside the point. I basically want to know if I am on a maintenance release of .net-4.6.2, if I am on a preview of .net-4.6.3, or if I am on a preview of .net-4.7. And I would like to have something that both uniquely identifies the release I’m running *and* carries the semantic MAJOR/MINOR/PATCH information.

Comment: @Ramhound I’m looking for the version with that key because it’s the version running on my computer. That key is the only way to uniquely identify each release of .net these days. I don’t know how to extract a version of the form `MAJOR.MINOR.PATCH.«whatever MS-specific build thing goes here»` from what I can find. At `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Full\1033` I read `CBS=1`, `Install=1`, `Release` is 395222 or 0x607d6, `Servicing=0`, `TargetVersion=4.0.0`, `Version=4.6.02006`, `SP` is not defined.

Comment: @Ramhound That article seems to be defining something *dstinct* from what .net framework will be shipped with Windows. It’s merely saying that both core+corefx and .netfx will overlap on the APIs defined by the “.net standard”. It does not imply that core will implement all of the APIs available in .netfx. That is why I say core is far from being able to actually replace .netfx in Windows. But maybe core without corefx but somehow mashed with the proprietary BCL from .netfx could replace .netfx. I am not keeping up with those things, though.

Comment: I think that chart just means that .net-4.6.3 or .net-4.7—whichever comes first or at all—will implement .NET Standard 1.6.

Comment: Removed my previous comments since I submitted an answer.  Comments are designed to be removed once they served their purpose.

Answer (score 0):

> What version of .net has a release key of 395222

Short Answer: vNext

Full Answer: Microsoft has not annouced what the version designation of the next version of the .NET Framework is.  They have annouced the next version of, [.NET Core](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/10/25/announcing-entity-framework-core-1-1-preview-1/) though, as `.NET Core 1.1`

[image]

Background Information:

> The .NET Standard Library is a formal specification of .NET APIs that
>   are intended to be available on all .NET runtimes. The motivation
>   behind the Standard Library is establishing greater uniformity in the
>   .NET ecosystem. ECMA 335 continues to establish uniformity for .NET
>   runtime behavior, but there is no similar spec for the .NET Base Class
>   Libraries (BCL) for .NET library implementations.

[.NET Standard Library](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/standard/library)

What is [.NET Standard](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/09/26/introducing-net-standard/)? - Microsoft's Explaination as of Sept 2016.  *This link is only background information and not relevant to the actual question that has been asked.*

> Based on the information on that page, the .net framework installed on
>   my computer is newer than .net-4.6.2.

It could also mean its simply an update version of 4.6.2.  So the only other possible explaination, due to the inability to confirm that 4.6.3 actually exists, is that the version of .NET Framework you have installed on your Insider Preview build of Windows 10 is still `4.6.2` which has simply been patched with the most recent updates.  I can't tell when, [.NET Framework Versions and Dependencies](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb822049%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) was last updated, I am going to guess it hasn't been since Aug 2nd 2016.

> These new releases apply to supported .NET Framework versions. This
>   means that you need to install a supported version of the .NET
>   Framework to get these updates. At the time of writing, the supported
>   versions are:
>
> - .NET Framework 3.5
> - .NET Framework 4.5.2 or later

[.NET Framework Monthly Rollups Explained](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/10/11/net-framework-monthly-rollups-explained/)

> I also looked at
>   %WINDIR%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\clr.dll’s FileVersion
>   and got 4.6.2006.0.
>
> Am I supposed to take the 02 and 006 from the 4.6.02006 in Visual
>   Studio to infer that I’m running .net-4.6.2 with a patchlevel of 6 or
>   something?

Read the following:

> For the .NET Framework Versions 4, 4.5, 4.5.1, and 4.5.2, the
>   Environment.Version property returns a Version object whose string
>   representation has the form 4.0.30319.xxxxx. For the .NET Framework
>   4.6, it has the form 4.0.30319.42000.
>
> For the .NET Framework 4.5 and later, we do not recommend using the
>   Environment.Version property to detect the version of the runtime.
>   Instead, we recommend that you query the registry, as described in the
>   To find .NET Framework versions by querying the registry in code (.NET
>   Framework 4.5 and later) section earlier in this article.

In other words you cannot infer anything from the file version with a 4.6.2 DLL

[How to: Determine Which .NET Framework Versions Are Installed](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh925568(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: [.NET Blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/) looked through 3 months worth of blog article I found no mention of what the version after 4.6.2 will be called besides vNext, I even looked at the Visual Studio 15 blog articles, absolutely nothing exists from what I can tell.